# Creating and filling a NxN grid in UWP Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I am trying to create a UWP puzzle game, I want to cut the picture into n parts and then show the pieces in a grid.

My problem is, how to force a certain NxN style. Right now I have to maximize the window in order to see a 3x3 grid, if I shrink either side, it will converge to a 2 column, 1 column grid. Is there a way to handle this?

This is what I have done, I know the RowDefinition is manually right now, until I figure out a better way to do that.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="PictureSplitter.Views.PictureView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">


        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Splitter.PuzzlePositions}">

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Grid x:Name="picGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Piece.ImageSource}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>

</UserControl>
```

This are two example images:
[image: Wanted gridstyle]

[image: Not wanted gridstyle]

Comment: Were you able to compile this code?

Comment: yes, otherwise i would not be able to post the picture.

Comment: I see. In .NET 4.5, ItemTemplate is not part of GridView. Anyway, I see your tag as UWP so probably it is working there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably couple of ways to do that, here is another one. I've modified the *UserControl* so that it automatically adjusts items size to show them as square grid, when page size changes and/or collection changes.

The UserControl XAML code:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyControls.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyControls"
    Name="myControl">

    <GridView Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=Items}"
              Width="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=CurrentWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Height="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Padding="10" Width="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=ElementSize}" Height="{Binding ElementName=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    public IList Items
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(IList), typeof(MyUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, (s, e) =>
            {
                if (Math.Sqrt((e.NewValue as IList).Count) % 1 != 0)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Bad Collection");
            }));

    public void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Math.Sqrt(Items.Count) % 1 != 0) Debug.WriteLine("Bad Collection");
        RaiseProperty(nameof(ElementSize));
    }

    private double currentWidth;
    public double CurrentWidth
    {
        get { return currentWidth; }
        set { currentWidth = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(CurrentWidth)); RaiseProperty(nameof(ElementSize)); }
    }

    public double ElementSize => (int)(currentWidth / (int)Math.Sqrt(Items.Count)) - 1;

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The MainPage XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myControl" Items="{Binding MyItems}"/>
    <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> myItems = new ObservableCollection<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    public ObservableCollection<int> MyItems
    {
        get { return myItems; }
        set { myItems = value; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyItems.CollectionChanged += myControl.Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        myControl.CurrentWidth = Math.Min(availableSize.Height, availableSize.Width);
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => MyItems.Add(3);
}
```

The program starts with "Bad Collection" - there are 8 items, so you can't make a square grid from them, but as soon as you click the provided button - the collection's count changes to 9 and the grid should update itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing this by way of MVVM, so I think you need to have a property for your Rows and Columns from your ViewModel. And then you need to have a Converter to supply the coordinate for your pieces .... OR an Attached property.

This will give you an idea:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <System:Int64 x:Key="X">3</System:Int64>
    <System:Int64 x:Key="Y">3</System:Int64>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    // You can bind column and row
    // <Button Content="image1" Grid.Column="{Binding column}" Grid.Row="{Binding row}"/>

    <Button Content="image1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Content="image2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Content="image3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <Button Content="image4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="image5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="image6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <Button Content="image7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button Content="image8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button Content="image9" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>

private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Int64 X = (Int64) this.FindResource("X");
    Int64 Y = (Int64) this.FindResource("Y");

    for (Int64 i = 0; i < X; i++)
    { 
        ColumnDefinition c = new ColumnDefinition();
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c);
    }
    for (Int64 i = 0; i < (int)Y; i++)
    {
        RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a ListView with GridView as it's View property. And it is working fine.

```
<ListView x:Name="ImageList" Width="210" Height="210">
    <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
          <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Control">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
          </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
          <GridViewColumn>                            
             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                       <Image Source="{Binding sq1}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>
           <GridViewColumn >
             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <Image Source="{Binding sq2}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <Image Source="{Binding sq3}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>    
       </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
```

```
var imgBox = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/images/cellbkg.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
var source = new[] { new { sq1 = imgBox, sq2 = imgBox, sq3 = imgBox }, new { sq1 = imgBox, sq2 = imgBox, sq3 = imgBox }, new { sq1 = imgBox, sq2 = imgBox, sq3 = imgBox } };    
ImageList.ItemsSource = source;
```

This code produces below output, and don't get collapsed if you reduce window size :

[image: 3x3 matrix display]

If this is what you want, you can add columns dynamically using below approach. For NxN matrix, you have to add only N columns, binding will take care of rest :

```
        GridView view = (GridView)ImageList.View;
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn());
```