# Add 3x10 = 30 grids dynamically in windows 8.1 runtime apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to add grids similar like this shown in picture in windows phone 8.1 app using C# only (without using XAML).

[image]

My code looks like:

In XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">

    </Grid>
```

In C# Code behind:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
   {
      Grid grid = new Grid();
      grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
      TextBlock intro = new TextBlock()
      {
         Text = i,
         FontSize = 10
      };
      grid.Children.Add(intro);
      ContentRoot.Children.Add(grid);
    }
}
```

*Is it possible to add entrance theme transition/animation on those grids through C# code?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at *GridView*.

Comment: I looked at it but no idea how to get started. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33593044/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add transistion-animation to the children.

Try the following code:

```
TransitionCollection tc = new TransitionCollection();
EntranceThemeTransition ett = new EntranceThemeTransition() { FromHorizontalOffset = 200, FromVerticalOffset = 200 };

ContentRoot.ChildrenTransitions = tc;

ContentRoot.ChildrenTransitions.Add(ett);
```

Hope it helps! :)